# TreeView - как использовать роль в качестве источника для картинки?

Tags: qml, treeview

Добрый день!
Имеется Tree view model, с определенными ролями. Отображаю ее в QML следующим образом:

```
TreeView {
        model: theModel
        itemDelegate: Rectangle {
            color: ( styleData.row % 2 == 0 ) ? "white" : "lightblue"
            height: 20
            Text {
                text: styleData.value === undefined ? "" : styleData.value
            }
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            width: 100
            role: "name_role"
            title: "Map"
        }
        TableViewColumn {
            width: 50
            role: "description_role"
            title: "Description"
        }

        Image {
            width: 15
            source: description_role + ".png"
            }

    }
```

Так вот во второй колонке значение роли прекрасно отображается, а когда пытаюсь использовать ее ниже в качестве ресурса для картинки - пишет что роль не определена (role is not defined)
Отсюда вопрос: Как правильно использовать роль в качестве источника для картинки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ нашелся, при более подробном чтении документации к TableViewColumn, к которому собственно и надо создать делегат следующим образом:

```
TreeView {
    model: theModel
    itemDelegate: Rectangle {
        color: ( styleData.row % 2 == 0 ) ? "white" : "lightblue"
        height: 20
        Text {
            text: styleData.value === undefined ? "" : styleData.value
        }
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        width: 100
        role: "name_role"
        title: "Map"
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        width: 50
        role: "description_role"
        title: "Description"
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        width: 50
        role: "description_role"
        title: "Icon"
        delegate: Image {
            source: styleData.value + ".png"
            }
        }

}
```